# Insert data into Cloud FireStore object type

Tags: android

I have a cloud firestore  collections with several documents.
Each document contains 1 object type field,in that object I have 3  fields.
How do I refer to object type inside doc and insert data into 3  fields  inside  that object

Answer (score 1):

If the document contains nested objects, you can use "dot notation" to reference nested fields in the document during the **update()** call:

```
// Assume doc1 contains:
// {
//   name: "Paul",
//   age: 10
//   favorites: { food: "Pizza", color: "Blue", subject: "recess" }
// }
//
// To update age and favorite color:

db.collection("MyCollection").document("doc1")
        .update(
                "name", "Dowy",
                "age", 24,
                "favorites.color", "Red"
        );
```

After That doc1 will look like:

```
// {
//   name: "Dowy",
//   age: 24
//   favorites: { food: "Pizza", color: "Red", subject: "recess" }
// }
```